# How to map a dataframe columns to dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe of two columns where one category (area_id) englobes the other one (location_id), how can I get a dictionary of lists where keys are the "area_id" and their respective values are lists of "location_id" present in the given "area_id"?

Concretely, given the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'area_id': ['area_1', 'area_1', 'area_1', 'area_2', 'area_2', 'area_3'],
                        'location_id': ['loc_a', 'loc_a', 'loc_b', 'loc_c', 'loc_d', 'loc_e']})
```

```
    area_id location_id
0   area_1  loc_a
1   area_1  loc_a
2   area_1  loc_b
3   area_2  loc_c
4   area_2  loc_d
5   area_3  loc_e
```

I would like the following dictionary:

```
{'area_1': ['loc_a', 'loc_b'],
 'area_2': ['loc_c', 'loc_d'],
 'area_3': ['loc_e']}
```

Code below is a working solution, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution which avoids using a "for" loop:

```
res = {}
for _area in df['area_id'].unique():
    _locs = list(df[df['area_id'] == _area]['location_id'].unique())
    res[_area] = _locs
```

Thank you

Comment: Use [`df.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: @bullseye It won't return the dictionary I am expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('area_id')['location_id'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'area_1': ['loc_a', 'loc_b'],
 'area_2': ['loc_c', 'loc_d'],
 'area_3': ['loc_e']}
```

Comment: @yoyoog Ah.. I didn't notice the duplicated values.

Comment: @yoyoog Be safe and stay healthy.